# Powershell, Invoke Web-Request Error (just at Windows Server 2012R)

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012-r2, synology, invoke-webrequest

at the moment i am writing some scripts to handle our Backups of our Costumers.
So the backups are running over a Synology Box.
The Script works really fine with Windows 10 and Windows Server 2019.
But i can not start it at WindowsServer 2012R2. And i tried so many things to handle but it didnt work.

```
$ip = "XXXXXXXXXX"
$u = "XXXXXXX"
$p = "XXXXXXX"
$d = "XXXXXX"

#Session ID auslesen & Authentifizierung
$a = Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing "http://$ip/webapi/auth.cgi?api=SYNO.API.Auth&version=2&method=login&account=$u&passwd=$p&session=ActiveBackup&format=cookie"
$ajson = $a.Content
$aobject = ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $ajson
$s = $aobject.data.sid
```

At first he shows me the error that he can not handle utf-8, ive updated Powershell to Version 5.1 and now Windows always tells me that the Value of $a is not allowed to be null. It Seems that he cannot receive any session Number. On Windows 10 and Windows Server 2019 it runs perfectly. Please can anybody help me please. Would beeee really nice

Greetings
Yaspo

Edit i got it.
For everybody who got the same problems just go the classic way without
invoke-webrequest

```
$url = "http://$ip/webapi/auth.cgi?api=SYNO.API.Auth&version=2&method=login&account=$u&passwd=$p&session=ActiveBackup&format=cookie"
$wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$result = $wc.DownloadString($url)
```